# Arduino % symbol meaning

Tags: arduino-uno

I dont know what meaning of this symbol - %.

for example,

buttonPressCount % numberOfLED == i

I hope anyone can tell me the name and basic function of this symbol.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was modded down so I gave it a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the modulus operator, and it performs the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

TL;CBR: It results in the remainder after division is performed.

Comment: It is also in the online Arduino reference: https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/modulo